# Why does the default keyboard always change after a phone restart?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note

I use a Samsung Galaxy Note phone with Jelly-Bean 4.1.2. I also use SwiftKey app as as my default keyboard. After every phone restart, the default keyboard changes to Samsung keyboard.

Why does the default keyboard setting change and how to make SwiftKey be the default keyboard..always?

Comment: Have you by any chance moved the SwiftKey app to SD Card via `Settings --> Apps --> SwiftKey --> Move to SD`?

Comment: @Chahk I didn't change anything. It says SD card app = 0B and Move to SD card button is disabled. I am going to ask at SwiftKey's site